# How should the html `height` and the `body's` `background-image` be handled?

Tags: html, css

I don't know how to better summarize the question, but here's the problem. I set my html's `height` to 100% as suggested by Kevin Powell and other peoples best practices so things like the footer and such use the whitespace and stick to the bottom of the page, however it presents the problem that if I want to give my `body` tag a `background-image` and the current page is "taller" than the viewport the image will start to repeat every 100% of the viewport, i.e. the 100% set by the `html` tag, which is not always the desired outcome.

How should I handle this, not to use `background-image` on my `body` tag? use a better tiling `background-image`?

P.S. I don't want to resort to having to wrap all my page's content on a wrapper `div` inside the `body` tag... unless well it's the only solution. The `body` tag has `min-height` of 100% I'm currently on Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is easily solvable by using

```
background-size: cover;
```

source

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size

You can also use just the **background** shorthand to set all the properties at once.

source

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background

Answer (score 0):

You can set `html` to occupy 100% of the user's screen by setting `min-height: 100vh`. then you could set `body` height to `height: 100%` to occupy the parent's height (HTML), so this way `html` and `body` have the same height if the content is not bigger than `100vh`.
If you want to have the same background as you scroll in the page, you can set `background-attachment: scroll` and `background-repeat: no-repeat`

something like this

```
html {
  min-height: 100vh;
}

body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-image: url( /* put your background url here */ );
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-attachment: scroll;
}
```

[background-attachment doc in MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-attachment)